# LVM system space is not consistent

Tags: filesystems, lvm

I have found some problem in my server, here it is:

```
df -H | columt -t

  Filesystem                    Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_home   212G  177G  25G    88%   /home

du -sh /home/

  59G   /home/
```

Does someone know why my `/home/` consume 59G space, but `vg_test_lv_home` have used 177G space, it does not make sense, right?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the `-H` option to `df` but not using the `--si` option for `du`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### difference between `du` and `df`

- `du` compute only what they can see, based on filesystem entries...
- `df` inquire filesytem meta datas

#### Deleted but not closed entries

There could be *deleted entries* that stay owned by running process.

```
(
    (
        dd if=/dev/zero count=102400
        sleep 5 ) >test.img  &
    sleep 1
    ls -l test.img
    df -k .
    du -xks /home
    rm -v test.img
    df -k .
    du -xks /home
    sleep 5
    df -k .
    du -xks /home
) 2>/dev/null
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 52428800 Jul 28 18:51 test.img
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/MyRX-HOME  10321208 7560824   2236096  78% /home
7159956     /home
removed `test.img'
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/MyRX-HOME  10321208 7560824   2236096  78% /home
7108756     /home
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/MyRX-HOME  10321208 7509472   2287448  77% /home
7108756     /home
```

While *file is removed*, used space stay at `7560824`, and return to `7509472` once first `sleep 5` finish (and redirected process finish).

#### Reserved block for sysadmin

There could be reservation by the filesystem (depending on which filesystem is used and how it is configured).

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_home
```

Comment: you are right,the running process hold the deleted file,/proc/12373/fd/1 -> /home/data/nohup.out (deleted)

Comment: If *I'm right* please valid the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense if the logical volume has been resized, but the underlying filesystem hasn't.

Try to run:

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_home
```

And then check again if the reported sizes match.

Comment: l haven't resized lvm